# Laravel with return null with datas create by my new form

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, relationship

Here my models :

// Specialties Model

```
class Specialties extends Model
{
  protected $guarded = [];

  protected $table = 'specialties';

  protected $primaryKey = 'id';

  protected $fillable = [
    'name', 'region_id', 'description', 'picture', 'url', 'author', 'code'
  ];

  public function regions() 
  {
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Regions', 'id');
  }
}
```

// Regions Model

```
class Regions extends Model
{
  protected $table = 'regions';

  protected $primaryKey = 'id';

  public function specialties() 
  {
    return $this->hasMany('App\Specialties', 'region_id');
  }
}
```

// My controller function to add new Specialties

```
public function store(Request $request, Recaptcha $recaptcha)
{
    $validatedData = $request->validate([
        'name' => 'required|string|max:50',
        'region' => 'required|integer',
        'description' => 'required|string|max:1000',
        'image_file' => 'required|file|mimes:jpeg,jpg,png,gif|max:2048',
        'url' => 'nullable|string|max:2000',
        'author' => 'nullable|string|max:50',
        'recaptcha' => ['required', $recaptcha],
    ]);

    Storage::disk('public')->putFileAs('/img/uploads/specialties', new File($validatedData['image_file']), pathinfo($validatedData['image_file']->getClientOriginalName(), PATHINFO_FILENAME) . time() . '.' . $validatedData['image_file']->getClientOriginalExtension());

    $code = str_slug($validatedData['name'], "-");

    $image_name = pathinfo($validatedData['image_file']->getClientOriginalName(), PATHINFO_FILENAME) . time() . '.' . $validatedData['image_file']->getClientOriginalExtension();

    $specialty = Specialties::create([
        'name' => $validatedData['name'],
        'region_id' => $validatedData['region'],
        'description' => $validatedData['description'],
        'picture' => $image_name,
        'url' => $validatedData['url'],
        'author' => $validatedData['author'],
        'code' => $code
    ]);

    return response(['specialty' => $specialty], 201);
}
```

// My function with the problem :

```
public function index()
{
    $actives = Specialties::with('regions')
        ->where('active', 1)
        ->get();
    $inactives = Specialties::with('regions')
        ->where('active', 0)
        ->get();

    return [
        'actives' => $actives,
        'inactives' => $inactives
    ];
}
```

My problem is that the with('regions') return null in the last function, for example if i create a new specialty "StackOverflow" :

```
active: 1
author: null
code: "stackoverflow"
created_at: "2020-09-24T16:59:29.000000Z"
description: "blablabla"
id: 18
name: "StackOverflow"
picture: "test600966769.jpg"
region_id: 1
regions: null <- Here the problem
updated_at: "2020-09-24T16:59:50.000000Z"
url: null
```

Anyone have an idea of the problem ? Thank's !!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

answer:

your `SpecialtiesModel` has wrong `regions function`,

explanation:

the `belongsTo` method 2nd parameter should be the `foreign key name` of current table model, the third parameter is the `primary key id` name of the reference table

example to your code:
`return $this->belongsTo('App\Regions', 'region_id');`